# WAX - How do I make it so the PiP can go anywhere?

Tags: video-editor

So, I make videos, and I needed to make a PiP of a comment in the video. I made the PiP, but whenever I move it upwards far enough, it gets hidden, as if there was an invisible video wall. To help you guys better understand it, I took a picture of my wax setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEUve.jpg
It's a bit hard to see, but you can see the top part hidden and such.

Thanks for reading, and thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: not really an answer to your question but may I suggest using Lightworks. It's a free modern NLE with support of many formats and modern user interface. You will get a lot more support and tutorials for this tool aswell.
http://www.lwks.com/

Comment: I don't really feel like making an account just to use it. :/